# Different signatures for passbook files

Tags: encryption, passbook

I am using [jpasskit](https://github.com/bitzeche/jpasskit) to generate and sign passes. So, I created a signature file from a sample manifest.json, using my p12 file and the Apple WWDRCA certificate. Then I decided to do the same thing (using the same manifest and certificates) using this [Objective C code](https://github.com/philippec/Ococoa/tree/master/Passbook/signpass%20tool/signpass). But the signature files are different from each other.

I suspect there is something wrong with the jpasskit code. So, is there any way to decrypt the signature or otherwise inspect them somehow to see what is wrong?

Comment: There is no reason that the files will be the same byte for byte.  Try to load a signed pass onto a device (not the simulator).  If it loads then the signature is ok, if not, then something is wrong. Your console logs should give sufficient info if there is a problem.

Comment: Yes, I've done that. But the error I get is "The passTypeIdentifier or teamIdentifier provided may not match your certificate, or the certificate trust chain could not be verified." I am sure I'm using the right passTypeIdentifier and teamIdentifier. And also the right p12 file. That's why I'd like to inspect or decrypt it, in order to maybe get more information.

Comment: Sounds like your signature is missing a signing date. This became a mandatory requirement in iOS7.

Comment: @PassKit Looking at the jpasskit source code, it seems it really doesn't add a signing date. Do you know how to do that using bouncycastle (which is what it uses for encryption)?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not a Java expert, but it shouldn't be to challenging for you to research.

Comment: Thanks, @PassKit. I figured it out and added the current date as the signing date, but I keep getting the same error :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52539/discussion-between-otavio-macedo-and-passkit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your pass signature (provide in chat), it looks like you are using an Apple Production IOS Push Services certificate (com.paguemob.mobileios.PagueMob) to sign your pass.

You need to be signing with a Pass Type ID certificate, and that certificate must match the name of the certificate you have in your pass.json (pass.com.paguemob.mobileios.PagueMobS).

Comment: The root of problem was in the AppleWWDRCA.cer file, which contained that wrong information. Thank you very much!